# Installing Lua Modules for use in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, modules, lua

I've done all of the searching that I can, and I think I've read the right answer, but am too dumb to know that I read it.

I can't seem to figure out the magic tricks to get Lua modules, installed by luarocks or by any other means, to show up in LuaLaTeX. So here is a minimal:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

    \directlua{package.path = "~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;" .. package.path }

    \directlua{require('pl')}
    \directlua{require('htk')}

    \directlua{tex.sprint(package.path)}

    the standard approximation $\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$

\end{document}
```

In installed `htk` using luarocks with the command `luarocks --local install HTK`
. The Penlight module was installed the same way, except with `penlight`. Penlight uses the "pl/submodulename" scheme and htk uses just "htk.lua" in the `~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1`
 directory.

The log output is:

```
./luamoduleload.tex:9: LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: module 'pl' not found:
    no field package.preload['pl']
    [luatexbase.loader] Search failed
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'pl'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'pl'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
l.9     \directlua{require('pl')}

The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

./luamoduleload.tex:10: LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: module 'htk' not found:
    no field package.preload['htk']
    [luatexbase.loader] Search failed
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'htk'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'htk'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
l.10    \directlua{require('htk')}

The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.
```

Would more of the log file be helpful?

In truth, if i just knew where to instal the lua modules that I want to use, I'd be a happy camper, especially if I don't need to do any magic tricks to get stand-alone lua scripts to work outside of LuaLaTeX.

Please let me know if I can be any clearer or if I'm not reading the right fine manuals. :)

-Andrew

Comment: Have you tried the CLUAINPUTS path? `texmf.cnf` says: `% Lua needs to look for binary lua libraries distributed with packages.
CLUAINPUTS = .;$SELFAUTOLOC/lib/{$progname,$engine,}/lua//`. Perhaps you can add the location where luarocks adds libraries to CLUAINPUTS.

Comment: So now that line looks like `CLUAINPUTS = .;$SELFAUTOLOC/lib/{$progname,$engine,}/lua//;~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1//` and it appears to have no effect... Cry ;)

Comment: How about adding the `.so` file in the current directory to see if dynamic loading works at all.

Comment: It does. If I drop the file into the project's directory it seems to work.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more about this "pl"? What is the exact name (the extension) of the module? Where do you want to store it? A small complete example with a simple `\directlua{require('pl')}` and the log-file would be useful too. E.g. I can't understand where the reference to `oberdiek.luatex.kpse_module_loader` comes from.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. Do the above edits work?

Comment: I just realized that your luarocks folder is in your home directory. I have not seen `~` in texmf.cnf files. Does it work if you replace `~` with `$HOME` or the complete path?

Comment: yeah. That didn't work. Seems to have the same issue with the same error in the log file. I should also explicitly mention that the standard Lua interpreter seems to find everything, just fine. :P I wonder, should I give up and just install everything within the project's tree? That seems like a crappy way to do it. :P I wonder if anyone has the "best practices way" that I should just use. I don't mind bending my methods toward a standard.

Comment: Within the `.tex` file, if I edit `package.path` to use `\$HOME`, I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input size=5000].`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Lua Modules for use in LuaLaTeX - the sequel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42878/installing-lua-modules-for-use-in-lualatex-the-sequel)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 \directlua{package.path = "~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;" .. package.path }
```

looks suspicious. I think you need to have `\noexpand`s before the tilde characters, otherwise the expansion of the `~` macro ends up as part of `package.path`.

```
\directlua{package.path = "\noexpand~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;\noexpand~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;" .. package.path }
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't matter as LuaLaTeX doesn't use `package.path` (or `package.cpath`) at all. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30444/250119

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but for completeness..

`\usepackage{luapackageloader}`

and place your Lua packages in you texmf directory (I put mine with the executable files), might have to refresh the filename database.

Eg: `C:\Users\PERSON\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\youPackagesHere`

Comment: This solution is also already mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372134/250119 (which also explains what the package do as well as its documentation/ctan package), and also *handle C package correctly*.