# "Lua tree" (analogue of texmf tree)

Tags: luatex

I have a lua file that I would use in many of my TeX's documents, loading it with dofile().

I thought it was ok if I simply put it in the (local) texmf tree*, but this doesn't work. Instead I have the following error message :

```
LuaTeX error cannot open the mycode.lua: No such file or directory
```

Is there any nice solution ?

- I try to save the file in ~/Library/texmf, in ~/Library/texmf/tex, ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex and even in ~/Library/texmf/lua (I had to create the directory).

Comment: Where precisely did you save the file?

Comment: How do you load the file? `require()`? `dofile()`?

Comment: Placing `file.lua` in the same folder and loading with `dofile("file.lua")` works, but I'd also be interested in a more general solution (especially since `dofile("/path/to/file.lua")` doesn't seem to work).

Comment: @scallops of course it works, but it isn't a nice and general solution at all. So we have to wait for the gurus :)

Comment: require() should normally use kpse. E.g. `require("fontspec.lua")` finds fontspec.lua in tex\latex\fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it works (if placed in ~/Library/texmf/tex/lua, with ~/Library/texmf/lua it doesn't work). Could you post your comment has an answer so I can accept it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dofile()` expects full path (or path relative to current directory). You have to either use `require()` which will search TEXMF tree, or use `kpse.find_file()` and pass the returned path to `dofile()`. `kpsewhich -show-path=lua` should show the search path for lua files.

Answer (score 12):

`require()` searches (TeXlive2011, LuaLaTeX) in these texmf subdirectories:

```
scripts/lualatex/lua/
scripts/luatex/lua
scripts/lua
scripts/lualatex
scripts/luatex
scripts
tex/lualatex
tex/latex
tex/luatex
tex/generic
tex
```

Comment: Where do you get this list from?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't remember. I believe it was something like `KPATHSEA_DEBUG=-1 lualatex ...` and parsed the output.

Comment: Oh. I thought maybe it was the output of some environmental variable.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218855/250119 for explanation on how require() works.

Answer (score 11):

`require()` should normally use kpse. E.g. `require("fontspec.lua")` finds `fontspec.lua` in `tex\latex\fontspec`.