# Which Lua environment should I use with LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX)?

Tags: luatex

### Lua code environment

I moved on to XeTeX (XeLaTeX) a while ago. I was using pdfLaTeX before that, but now I'm quite comfortable with XeLaTeX.

Now, I'd like to use LuaLaTeX to embed Lua in some LaTeX documents. The [doc](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX) states several ways to embed Lua in TeX, but they confuse me more than actually explain what I need to know about embedding Lua.

There's `\directlua{ ... }`, `\luacode ... \endluacode`, and `\begin{luacode} ... \end{luacode}` with the *luacode* package. The dots (`...`) is where Lua code would go.

Now, which one should I use?

And is there a quicker way to enter Lua environment like with math mode where I can enter mathmode with '`$`'?

### Saving variables

A quick one: When using Lua code embedded in LuaLaTeX, all variables are lost when the code finishes. Now, can I save return values, etc. so I can use them in my document later, with `\myvar` for sinstance, or something?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are two questions here. You should consider asking one question at a time for your next posts.

Now to the **Lua code environment**. Don't use any of them if you can. Just do

```
\directlua{  require("myfile")  }
```

and put all of your Lua code in that file. See [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/lua-tree-analogue-of-texmf-tree/31904#31904) for a list of directories TeX searches for the file `myfile.lua`.

If for some reason you can't do that (when you are only allowed to ship only one file for example) you should use the environment `luacode*` (with `*`) from the *luacode* package. That has the safest character catcodes. That means you can say something like:

```
\begin{luacode*}
texio.write_nl("This is a string with\n a newline in it")
tex.print(-2, string.format( "5 %% 4 is %d ", 5 % 4))
\end{luacode*}
```

*(You need the `-2` as the first argument to `tex.sprint()`, because the `%` sign (resulting from the double `%%` is interpreted from TeX as a comment sign after the environment closes. TeX sees at the end of the environment `5 % 4 is 1` and treats the `%` as the end of input. So you need to tell TeX that this `%` is a regular character. You have two choices: either pass TeX a string like this: `string.format("5 \\%% 4 is ...")` so that TeX sees `5 \% 4 is ...` as you would do with normal text or make `%` a normal letter, so TeX does not recognize it as a comment sign. To do that you have to change the category code. The easiest way is to assign the special  catcode table -2 to `tex.print()`. It is a safe catcode table, no characters have a special meaning.)*

If you need to use TeX macros in Lua code, use the `luacode` environment (without `*`):

```
\begin{luacode}
    local current_page = tonumber(\thepage)
    texio.write_nl("We are on page " .. current_page)
\end{luacode}
```

And if you need to put your code in a command, use `\luaexec`:

```
\newcommand\myrepeat[2]{%
\luaexec{
  for i=1,#1 do
     tex.sprint("\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")
   end
 }}

\myrepeat{4}{Hello world}
```

(you can't use the environments directly in a `\newcommand`, but you could use `\luacodestar` ... `\endluacodestar` if you really want the environment functionality). The `\luatexluaescapestring{}` is necessary to escape input characters like `"` that would be harmful to the Lua string.

You have also asked if there is a shortcut such as the `$`...`$` for math typesetting. No, there is none. IMO that is not such a big problem, as Lua code (in practice, but YMMV) is only used at a few points (with macros or with environments for example) and not so much in running text. Mostly in packages. (See the [documentation](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/luacolor.pdf) to the [luacolor package](http://ctan.org/pkg/luacolor) for example.  Even if you don't understand the package in full detail at the first glance, you can see where the TeX code is with the `\directlua` calls, aliased in the example to `\LuaCol@directlua` and how the Lua code is separated from it in another file. See that there are only very few lines of Lua code inside the `\LuaCol@directlua` commands? In my opinion we can learn a lot from this code, as Heiko Oberdiek is an excellent package writer.)

Now to your second question about **Saving variables**. If you don't declare your variables local, they are accessible in all Lua chunks. But you are asking to pass Lua code to TeX. You can do this for example:

```
\begin{luacode*}
tex.sprint("\setcounter{mycounter}{" .. my_lua_value .. "}")
\end{luacode*}
```

to create a `\setcounter` command with your value. Or you can use the `tex.count` Lua interface:

```
\begin{luacode*}
tex.count[10] = my_lua_value
\end{luacode*}
```

and your value is in `\count10`. But this is a bit dangerous as you have to be certain to use a free counter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. When defining a command, couldn't I use `\directlua{}` just as well? Or is there a significant difference with `\luaexec{}`?

Comment: @polemon You can use `\directlua{}` instead. But all kinds of characters will spoil your experience: `%`, `\ `, `--`, `\\ ` and `~`. You have to be careful and escape them. I strongly suggest to define a function in a separate lua file and call that function from your `\directlua{}` or `\luaexec{}` command. Then you don't have to worry about TeX interpreting some funny characters even before Lua gets to see them.

Comment: Your example with `\repeat{4}{Hello world\par}` does not work here with LuaTeX from MiKTeX 2.9. I get the error message
 
    `{ for i=1,4 do tex.sprint("\luatexluaescapestring {Hello world
    ! Paragraph ended before \luaexec was complete.
    <to be read again>
                       \par
    l.28 \repeat{4}{Hello world\par}`
It works nicely without `\par` though, is this somehow not allowed in this command?

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the pointer. My example was broken. I can't really tell why it failed due to lack of internal insight.

Comment: @Patrick This is most likely because a macro (`\luaexec` it seems) was not defined to be long.

Comment: I'm struggeling with catcodes: How do I get a `\tex.sprint` inside a `\luaexec` in a LaTeX command to correctly handle the `@`, i.e. do a `\tex.sprint("\\foo@bar")`? `tex.sprint(-1,...)` doesn't help, and -2 looses the meaning of \.

Comment: @MartinSchröder have you tried `tex.tprint()`? Without looking at the manual, I guess the following could do: `tex.tprint({"\\"},{-2,"foo@bar"})`. But IIRC -2 changes the catcodes to 'other' which doesn't help with command names. Perhaps surround this with `\makeat...`?