# How to check for Lua definitions

Tags: luatex

When there is `\directlua{x = 25}` one can say `\edef\rgf{\directlua{tex.sprint(x)}}`, but when `x` was never created by `\directlua{x = 25}`, `\directlua{tex.sprint(x)}` will fail. Thus something like `\@ifundefined{x}{x undefined}{x defined}` would be nice. How does one "say this in Lua", please?

Comment: May be you 'd try reading some general lua programming documentation first.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: I tried but did not find it there. Any suggestion for better lua-documentation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint( x or 42 ) }
```

or perhaps

```
\directlua{
  if x then
    tex.sprint(x)
  % else
    % do something else
  end
}
```

Comment: But see also the question [about using `luacode` and `\directlua{}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33096/243)

Comment: Thanks, it works! (Upvoted & accepted.) Also your answer to the other question is enlightening, but unfortunately with that question title one does not find it without being told that it is there.