# LuaLaTeX, sprint verbatim text

Tags: luatex

The code below, uses the `lua`, `socket.http` library to pull a web page (for simplicity I have used a link to a text file). I have used `tex.sprint` to pass it back to the typesetting engine. However I would have preferred to print within a `verbatim` environment or preferably using the `listings` environment. Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\&=12
\directlua{
```

```lua
local http = require("socket.http")
function url_encode(str)
  if (str) then
    str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\r\string\n")
    str = string.gsub (str, "([^%w ])",
        function (c) return string.format ("%%%02X", string.byte(c)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
  end
  return str
end
function url_decode(str)
  str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
  str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)",
      function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
  str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\n")
  return str
end
 local page  = http.request( 'http://mirror-cybernet.lums.edu.pk/pub/ctan/dviware/screenview/vms/test.txt' )
tex.sprint(page)
```

```
}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Note, the MWE contains two functions that I haven't used, for encoding and decoding the url. I left them in case you want to try a different `url`. As a sideline I find it  amazing that old 'TeX' in new clothes can talk to the web.

Comment: I put in a lua language hint for the syntax highlighter. This split your code block into three, but it still seems to copy and paste fine. I won't be at all offended if you want to roll it back!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. don't use `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` in your document as utf8 is the default
2. Put the Lua code in a separate file. If that is not feasible, use the `luacode*` environment from the `luacode` package See the [question about luacode enviroments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33096/which-lua-environment-should-i-use-with-luatex-lualatex). Then you don't need to mess with the cat codes.
3. The two functions you define are not used (and are unnecessary).

Here is a solution which works with the listings environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local http = require("socket.http")
local page  = http.request( 'http://mirror-cybernet.lums.edu.pk/pub/ctan/dviware/screenview/vms/test.txt' )

tex.print("\\begin{lstlisting}")
tex.print(page:gsub("\n","\r"))
tex.print("\\end{lstlisting}")
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, just finding my way through Lua:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I have to admit that it took me a few attempts to get the above code right. I first tried with verbatim (from the verbatim package) and then with lstlistings. Finally I chose to do the `gsub` above and all the problems went away. I *strongly* suggest to separate Lua and TeX code by putting the Lua code in some extra file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to separate the Lua code in another file, it is more tidy as well.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: Any idea why substituting `\n` to `\r` is not needed in ConTeXt?

Comment: @Aditya no idea. I guess its one of the magic things ConTeXt has built in.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, in ConTeXt you can simply use

```
\starttext
\typefile{http://mirror-cybernet.lums.edu.pk/pub/ctan/dviware/screenview/vms/test.txt}
\stoptext
```

to load a file from the net. Almost all file loading macros use the socket library to download (and cache) the file, if a url is specified.

If you want to do this manually, the following works:

```
\starttext
\startluacode
local http = require("socket.http")
local page  = http.request( 'http://mirror-cybernet.lums.edu.pk/pub/ctan/dviware/screenview/vms/test.txt' )
tex.print(string.format("\\starttyping %s \\stoptyping", page))
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

(I could not get the similar code to work in LuaLaTeX because the `luacode` environment in LaTeX uses different catcodes than the `luacode` environment in ConTeXt)