# LuaLaTeX issue with string (need to escape)

Tags: luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print large macro block from Lua to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49811/print-large-macro-block-from-lua-to-tex)

I need to escape a string in Lua code in LuaLaTeX. I'm trying to print a string but LaTeX seems to hiccup on some special characters. I know I can call `\luatexluaescapestring` from inside text but I need an equivalent function in Lua that will either remove the offending characters or escape them properly.

Comment: What are the special characters that give the problem?

Comment: I am really really very happy now and I have no intention for another comment flaming but I am really trying to understand why you are reluctant to post a simple code example. It has been the topic of your previous questions for no reason but why again I wonder.

Comment: I have the feeling that I've just answered this on your [last question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49847/243). I think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: By "offending characters" you mean the literal ones? The Lua Reference Manual recommends to use literal strings (`[[ one\ntwo ]]`) in this case (the literal char `\n` is already escaped). I'm not sure Lua has a built-in function for this (they explicitly recommend literal strings for escaping literal chars), but maybe a solution is to write a local function which `string.sub`'s all the 14 literal chars and return a "clean" string. `:)`

Comment: Please no further down-voting, as it isn't productive.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach This is not the same question. They have nothing to do with one another. One is to print a string literal that represents a tex macro and one is to print a variable with some type of character in it that is causing tex to crap out. It turns out it is the '_' characters and tex is wanting to go into math mode. I had no issues with the code before but something changed causing problems.

Comment: @Uiy did you actually try my code in the other question? It doesn't seem so. Otherwise the underscore `_` would not have had any problem. Next time, please provide a minimal example!