# Use lualatex to create macros

Tags: macros, luatex

I used the following in the past and it worked:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
MyVal=123
tex.print("\\def\\MyVal{"..MyVal.."}")
\end{luacode*}

MyVal=\MyVal
\end{document}
```

and it worked fine.

Today I had to use the same source file and now this bit of code no longer defines a macro that can be called in `lualatex`, i.e. I now get `Undefined command` message.

I read the following:
[Which Lua environment should I use with LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33096/which-lua-environment-should-i-use-with-luatex-lualatex/33102#33102)
and
[Create macros inside Lua block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48414/create-macros-inside-lua-block)

I tried `luacode` sans and with '*' as well as `tex.sprint`.

I attempted `tex.tprint`, but I will have to delve in the documentation about that.

My questions then are:

1. Has anything changed in the last two months?
2. How would one do the equivalent of the following in `lualatex`:

   ```
   \def{Myval}{100}
   ```

I also added `\noexpand` and changed `\\` to `\`, to no avail.

Comment: See also: [luatex - token.set_macro: \directlua vs. luacode* - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464465/token-set-macro-directlua-vs-luacode) (same answer but with `token.set_macro` Lua function)

Comment: @user202729 thank you for your contribution --- although eight years later.

Comment: (Left for future readers. Some may come across this one while searching the Internet.)

Comment: @user202729 I would rather start a new posting with reference to this one.

Comment: No I mean they might come across this question while searching for some search terms, but the question isn't really the one they're looking for. Why create new post? The question/answer is already there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `luacode*` environment forms a group, in common with other LaTeX environments. Thus if you want to use this approach and have the value 'escape' then you will need to use `\gdef`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
MyVal=123
tex.print("\\gdef\\MyVal{"..MyVal.."}")
\end{luacode*}

MyVal=\MyVal
\end{document}
```

As observed in [Which Lua environment should I use with LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33096/which-lua-environment-should-i-use-with-luatex-lualatex/33102#33102), the best plan is to use a separate file and load it without grouping, *etc.*

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.lua}
MyVal=123
tex.print("\\def\\MyVal{"..MyVal.."}")
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\directlua{require("\jobname.lua")}

MyVal=\MyVal
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a ConTeXt user who regularly uses lua to define macros, I find it strange that the `luacode*` environment creates a group.  Writing lua code in a separate file is fine, but sometimes having all related macros in one file is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Aditya LaTeX's `\begin`...`\end` always creates a group (except `\begin{document}`, which deliberately undoes this). Normally if you want to avoid it you use `\foo`...`\endfoo` instead, although this is not officially supported. It's of course possible to undo the group creation: it might well be sensible here but that is for the author of `luacode*` to decide and document!

Comment: (`\document` starts with `\endgroup` and `\enddocument` contains a `\begingroup` to 'neutralise' the matching grouping primitives in `\begin` and `\end`.)

Comment: @Aditya I do see the point about inline code for short sections (we have some in `expl3`).

Comment: @JosephWright I would not use the include method in my case, I define macros with values to a problem and I use the values to calculate the answers when I generate the solutions.  I could name each problem's set different and according to the problem but that would mean that the text and macro's values become to far separated and I would page too many times up and down while I edit the document.  (And `pdfsync functionality` does not return to lua code.)

Answer (score 7):

If you only need to export a value as a macro, i.e. a macro without a signature, then you could also use the `token` library of LuaTeX.  The same as in Joseph's answer applies here:  Because `luacode*` is grouping you have to add the `"global"` specifier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
MyVal = 123
token.set_macro("MyVal",MyVal,"global")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\MyVal
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In ConTeXt MkIV you do not need to declare the control sequence global because here `\startluacode ... \stopluacode` is *not* grouping.

```
\startluacode
MyVal = 123
token.set_macro("MyVal",MyVal)
\stopluacode
\starttext
\MyVal
\stoptext
```