# Defining new commands from LuaTeX

Tags: luatex

Latex provides several commands relating to creating new commands such as `\newcommand`. If I want to define new commands from a Lua script one way is use `tex.print` to write this directly into the document.

It this really the best way though? The whole point of LuaTeX is to avoid programming with Tex macros, yet this approaches involves doing exactly that. How can I directly access, edit and create commands directly from Lua?

#### script.lua

```
tex.print("\\newcommand{\\hello}{Hello world}")
```

#### document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \directlua{ require("script") }
    \hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: LuaTeX is about _combining_ Lua and TeX: if you look at ConTeXt, it is still a macro system _using Lua _where it adds functionality_

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you're driving at. Combining Lua and (La)TeX is my objective. How does ConTeXt fit into the picture? What distinction are you pointing out?

Comment: LuaTeX is developed by the ConTeXt developers: Hans _et al._ more than anyone know where to use Lua in a TeX system. They don't try to define everything from Lua: they use a mix, depending on what makes most sense. For macro definition, it's  almost always going to be clearest and easiest to do things from the 'TeX side'.

Comment: Note that if you use the `luacode` environment instead see [luatex - Use lualatex to create macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129046/use-lualatex-to-create-macros)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \directlua{token.set_macro("hello","goodbye") }
    \hello
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted, thank you. Do you know of any good packages/classes on CTAN I could look at that are implemented in Lua and do this sort of thing? (To try to understand the common patterns a bit better. I'm looking at building a document class)

Comment: @raiksey I think it's rather rare to be setting tex macros from lua, code either is all in tex or all the way to typesetting in lua, this is half and half, it can be useful sometimes though.

Comment: To outline my problem at a higher level, I'm trying to create (or adapt) a CV document class/template. Rather than deal with tex macros which are infamously difficult to wrangle with, I thought it would be a better approach to code the "logic" of the template in lua using Luatex, but still have the class be usable much like any other document class, with custom latex commands for cv sections, social media handles etc. Hence the need to define new commands in lua. Is this not a reasonable approach? This is all very much a learning experience for me.

Comment: @raiksey it is much easier to define tex commands from the tex side than the lua side. In tex you have the tex parser available so the definition is automatically tokenised, but in lua if you are not just defining a simple string as here you'd have to build up the tokens "by hand".

Comment: To add a use case for `token.set_macro`: for a CI pipeline, I am fetching git metadata (in this example, short SHA and ref name) from environment variables (as predefined by the CI env), to print in the PDF. If those aren't available, fallback commands like `git rev-parse --short HEAD` are tried (e.g. for local compilation). The result (just a string) is written into a macro using `set_macro`. Accessing env variables (`os.getenv`) and running outside commands (`pcall`, `io.popen`) is easy to do in Lua but, as far as I know, much, much harder in (La)TeX.

Comment: @AlexPovel yes as I say if the macro replacement text is a string the lua setting has better use cases, but if you want to do the equivalent of `\def\foo{$\sqrt{\phi}+\cos 2$}` then doing it in tex is a lot easier than doing it in lua as you would have to build each token separately and build up the token list.