# token.set_macro: \directlua vs. luacode*

Tags: luatex, luacode, directlua

If I compile the following code with LuaLaTeX I get the word "RED" as output. The call of `token.set_macro` inside of `luacode*` seems to be noneffective.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand*\foo{RED}

\iftrue
\begin{luacode*}
  token.set_macro('foo', 'GREEN')
\end{luacode*}
\else  
  \directlua{token.set_macro('foo', 'GREEN')}
\fi  

\begin{document}
  \foo
\end{document}
```

After changing `\iftrue` to `\iffalse` I get "GREEN". Can anyone explain this behavior? Many thanks.

Comment: Of course as a workaround it's possible to define a function in the luacode and call that function in directlua, so it's executed at the current TeX grouping level. // See also: [luatex - token.set_macro: \directlua vs. luacode* - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464465/token-set-macro-directlua-vs-luacode) (same answer but uses `tex.print` to print the `\def` to TeX)

Comment: Remark, it's possible for the package to "fix" that, see [scoping - How can I escape the scope of an environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-can-i-escape-the-scope-of-an-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An environment is a group, if you add a group in the `\directlua` case, then you see the same:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand*\foo{RED}

\iffalse
\begin{luacode*}
  token.set_macro('foo', 'GREEN')
\end{luacode*}
\else
{  
  \directlua{token.set_macro('foo', 'GREEN')}
}
\fi  

\begin{document}
  \foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, so easy is the explanation. I must write `token.set_macro('foo', 'GREEN', 'global')`. Many thanks, David.

Comment: @rolfn you could, although personally I'm not convinced by the need for the luacode environments, and I'd probably use `\directlua` directly.