# Inject LaTeX code 1:1 with LuaLaTeX

Tags: beamer, luatex

I would like to automate the creation of some `beamer` slides using LuaLaTeX. These are my first steps with LuaLaTeX so please excuse my ignorance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
  for i=0, 5 do
    tex.print("\unexpanded{\\begin{frame}}")
    tex.print("Math: $x_{" .. i .. "}$")
    tex.print("\unexpanded{\\end{frame}}")
  end
}

\end{document}
```

The example compiles and gives the expected result; 6 frames with x_0,1,2,3,5 on it.

I'm a bit unhappy about the additional `\unexpand`s and `\`s before `\begin` and `\end`.

Is there a dedicated LuaTeX command that just inserts latex code 1:1 to the document?

Comment: You might find [Which Lua environment should I use with LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33096/which-lua-environment-should-i-use-with-luatex-lualatex) useful.

Answer (score 2):

a short `\frame{..}` is possible

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
  for i=0, 5 do
    tex.print("\string\\frame{")
    tex.print("Math: $x_{" .. i .. "}$")
    tex.print("}")
  end
}

\end{document}
```