# Access defined Lua global variables in TeX macros‏

Tags: luatex

I am a newbie in LuaTeX, but it is very interesting.

Sometimes, I need process some macro arguments by Lua code, so it will be useful that if we can access the variables defined in Lua. An example:

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \directlua{var = [[#1]] .. " " .. system}
  % other part of this macro
  ...}

\foo{typesetting}

\bye
```

how can I access the `var` defined in the `\directlua`? Say, after `\foo{typesetting}`, I can get `typesetting system` by only using the `var`.

---

Another question is that `how can I access the TeX command in \directlua environment`?

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I access the TeX command in \directlua environment?" What kind of access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See my answer here: [Which Lua environment should I use with LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33096/which-lua-environment-should-i-use-with-luatex-lualatex/33102#33102)

You can do this:

```
\newcommand\myrepeat[2]{%
\luaexec{
  for i=1,#1 do
     tex.sprint("\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")
   end
 }}

\myrepeat{4}{Hello world}
```

to access the macro parameters.

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{%
   \directlua{myvar=\luatexluaescapestring{#1}}}
```

should be enough to assign parameter 1 to the variable `myvar`.

For your plain TeX solution, this prints out 'typesetting system':

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \directlua{var = [[\luaescapestring{#1}]] .. " system"
  tex.sprint(var)
}% other part of this macro
}

\foo{typesetting}

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am using plain LuaTeX(so, I can't use the `\luatexluaescapestring`), are there any methods to achieve that? As the example I have given, after `\foo{typesetting}`, I should get `typesetting system`.

Comment: thanks, topskip. I have read your answer carefully. What part of the lua programming language do you think it is enough to program in lua when using LuaTeX?

Comment: @TimLi Since Lua's syntax is not really big, I'd say "everything except for the `:` notation". But this depends on the problem you're trying to solve. If you look at my profile/answers, you find some LuaTeX answers that manipulate the nodelists. These might give you an idea about the average LuaTeX program. You can also look at https://github.com/speedata/publisher/tree/develop/ (in the subdir "src/lua" for a more advanced LuaTeX program.

Comment: Thanks for your advice(now, I think I should read the PIL from cover to cover). I have read your answers to somebody before. It is impressive that your magic Lua code can manipulate the node lists so freely. At that time, I decide to learn Lua and LuaTeX.

Comment: @TimLi it's not _my_ magic but the magic of the LuaTeX developers (by providing callbacks and such). My routines tend to be rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean using the variable also outside of Lua, right?

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \directlua{var = "Year: " .. [[\luaescapestring{#1}]]
    tex.sprint(var)
    tex.sprint{"\string\\def\string\\var{\luaescapestring{#1}}"}
  }% other part of this macro
}

\foo{\the\year}

\var
\bye
```

with the output:

[image]

Comment: thanks. Is it mean that I write `\directlua{tex.sprint"\string\\def\string\\var{hello}"}` is like writing `\def\var{hello}` directly in the Knuth82? It seems like so.

Comment: sure, but that is only a simple example. There can be other sitatuations where it makes sense to define a TeX macro inside Lua.

Comment: yeah, I see its potential. We can deal with something(Do you think CVS is OK?) by using Lua, which maybe is difficult for TeX82. Where can I find some examples about using Lua in LuaTeX? (I am learning the Lua programming language, so I only want some examples which can show me what LuaTeX can do better and easier than TeX82 or pdfTeX)