# LuaLatex package: \dofile results in error "no such file or directory"

Tags: luatex, package-writing

I've written some macros that randomly selects questions from a database to include on an exam.  The start of my `.sty` file reads as follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{randqs}[2012/10/23 ver 0.1]

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\directlua{dofile('randqs.lua')}
```

It seems that in my document, when I call

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{randqs}
```

LuaTex (or whoever) is searching for `randqs.lua` in the directory of the `.tex` file rather than in the directory of the `.sty` file because if the `.lua` is in the former then it is found, while if it is in the latter then it is not.  I'm guessing that `dofile` is not the way to go here, so my question is:  how do I ensure that LuaTex (or whoever) looks for the file in the `.sty` directory rather than the `.tex` directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dofile()` is a [Lua command](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile) and looks for a file with the given path, in your case `randqs.lua` in the current directory, because you've given a relative path. There are two choices here:

1. give a relative path to the style file (or an absolute path), but this is non portable, of course.
2. or use `require('randqs')` (without `.lua`) to load the file. But beware: `require()` uses a special search path, see my answer to another question: ["Lua tree" (analogue of texmf tree)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/lua-tree-analogue-of-texmf-tree/31904#31904)
3. From Khaled: A third option is to locate the file using kpse library, e.g. `dofile(kpse.find_file("randqs.lua"))`

Comment: A third option is to locate the file using `kpse` library, e.g. `dofile(kpse.find_file("randqs.lua"))`.

Comment: @KhaledHosny, topskip: Thank you both, after refreshing my file name database, both the `kpse.find` and `require` methods work.  Is there any reason to prefer one to the other?

Comment: @KhaledHosny I keep forgetting about that. Thanks

Comment: @ScottH.: I’m not sure, `require()` looks cleaner, but `kpse.find_file()` might give you a bit more control on how to locate the files (LuaTeX manual gives more details on what options you can pass to it).