# HowTo create a LuaLatex package

Tags: luatex, package-writing

I would like to develop LuaLatex packages. I am very interested by the scripting capability of LuaLatex, so I'd like to use it as much as possible instead of Latex or Tex.

Is there a "standard" or "time-tested" way to write a LuaLatex packages?

What is the main differences/similarities between Latex packaging and LuaLatex packaging?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think you must differ between a latex `.sty` and a direct `.lua` package.

Comment: You mean, instead of using:
    \usepackage{myPackage}
I should use:
    dofile("myPackage.lua")

Comment: No, in writing ... Some `.lua` code packages are included within an importing `.sty` file, most times having the same basename, i.e.  `foo.sty` imports `foo.lua`, but I am not an expert in luatex, others should provide more profound answers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Note about dofile: it might not work [luatex - LuaLatex package: \dofile results in error "no such file or directory" - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79216/lualatex-package-dofile-results-in-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 9):

It all depends...

luatex is a two-language system and a lualatex package can use either language.

You could write a package written just as a classic latex package but using some of the extended tex commands available in luatex, such as `\umathchar` etc.

You could write code that is almost all Lua, with just a very thin TeX wrapper `mypackage.sty` that just does `\directlua{require("mypackage")}` (`luaotfload` comes to mind)

There isn't really a lot in common between these kinds of packages other than that the end user doesn't necessarily need to know anything about the implementation language, and can just do

```
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

In one case, The coding practices are just as in classic TeX, in the other case, the coding practices are those of Lua (mostly).