# loading Lua helper scripts in documentclass packages

Tags: luatex, documentclass-writing, ctan

This question is about organising files in a package for CTAN.

How can I load `lua` and `tex` helper files in the documentclass so that they are found when the package is installed in the TeXLive folders?

I would like to upload this package to CTAN: [wallcalendar](https://github.com/profound-labs/wallcalendar)

Some of its functionality depends on running helper Lua functions which are collected in a helper script and used this way:

```
\luadirect{
require("./scripts/wallcalendar-helpers.lua")
monthEvents(
  \luastring{\@t@monthName},
  \@t@filterPred,
  \@t@formatFunc,
  \luastringO{\@t@formatCmd},
  \luastring{\@t@eventsCsv},
  \luastring{\@t@markDefaultsCsv},
  \@t@minEvents
)}}
```

And there are helper `tex` files which define names of things for a given language, such as [i18n/hungarian.tex](https://github.com/profound-labs/wallcalendar/blob/master/i18n/hungarian.tex)

Used this way:

```
% Load internal translations
\InputIfFileExists{i18n/\@wall@calendarLanguage.tex}{}%
{\ClassError{wallcalendar}{File Not Found: i18n/\@wall@calendarLanguage.tex}{}}
```

These methods only work when the files are copied in the project folder (where the user's document such as `mycalendar.tex` is).

Comment: As texlive's hierarchy is flat and indexed by kpse you could do the following: `kpse.find_file("wallcalendar-helpers.lua")`. This will return the correct path to the script (to be used in you require).

Comment: require uses kpathsea, so it will find files in e.g tex/latex/wallcalendar.

Comment: @TeXnician you don't need to explicitly call `kpse` it is built in to Lua's default input search in luatex.

Comment: Mostly same question as [luatex - LuaLatex package: \dofile results in error "no such file or directory" - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79216/lualatex-package-dofile-results-in-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to arrange that `wallpaper.lua` is in the same directory as the package file (actually anywhere in tex's input path but alongside the package is simplest for distributing and then)

```
\directlua{require('wallpaper')}
```

any recent version of luatex will default the `.lua` extension and find the file via the usual tex input path search.

similarly

```
\InputIfFileExists{i18n/\@wall@calendarLanguage.tex}
```

should work as long as the `i18n` directory is in the standard places searched by kpathsea  (although a simpler alternative would be to use

```
\InputIfFileExist{\@wall@calendarLanguage}
```

and put all the language files in the same directory as your class file in the installed version.