# LuaLaTeX require path -- only absolute paths work

Tags: luatex, lua, texmf

I would like to use external packages for LuaLaTeX scripting (eg.`penlight`). I often test my scripts with `texlua` command without issues. However, I noticed when I compile the document with the `lualatex` command, an error is raised on `require()`. I am certain that `package.path` and `package.cpath` contain the directories where my external modules are stored. It seems like I can add modules by providing the absolute path to the external module, but this becomes an issue if the module relatively references another one.

So in summary, `require()` with relative paths is not working for `lualatex`, but works for `texlua` commands.

I know this is a related question, but it is 2011 and the solution is inelegant as I would have to manually change the `require` call for each external module. ["Lua tree" (analogue of texmf tree)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/lua-tree-analogue-of-texmf-tree/)

**Main.tex**

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\directlua{dofile("FileInSameDirAsMainAndRequiresExternalModules.lua")}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

**FileInSameDirAsMainAndRequiresExternalModules.lua**

```lua
_LUA_STUFF_DIR = 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64' --just to be sure the path is there...
package.path = package.path..';'.._LUA_STUFF_DIR
package.cpath = package.cpath..';'.._LUA_STUFF_DIR --todo why does this not work for luatex but texlua
--Both calls below work with texlua command
pl = require('pl') -- this fails with lualatex as pl is not found
pl = require(_LUA_STUFF_DIR..'/pl/tablex') -- this also fails with lualatex, but differently
--it "gets" through to the pl.tablex module, but fails since tablex.lua had a require(pl.util) in it
```

**Edit: Also tested this with the same issue**

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\directlua{
LUASTUFFDIR = 'C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64'
package.path = package.path..';'..LUASTUFFDIR
package.cpath = package.cpath..';'..LUASTUFFDIR
pl = require('pl')
}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `"./FileInSameDirAsMainAndRequiresExternalModules.lua"` ?

Comment: Yes, same issue--and that's because the problem is NOT that main.tex cannot find the `"./FileInSameDirAsMainAndRequiresExternalModules.lua"`, it is because that `.lua` file fails on the `require` call is failing for relative paths--or perhaps `require` is not using `package.path` or `package.cpath` when searching. As I pointed out, I don't want to have to modify every module to point to an absolute path.

Comment: when used with lualatex, the package search code is replaced and then use kpathsea. See the documentation of luapackageloader https://ctan.org/pkg/luapackageloader

Comment: Thanks, the frustrating part for me is that I've seen than package come up before and forgot about. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Answer (score 0):

As @UlrikeFischer pointed out, the `\usepackage{luapackageloader}` solved the issue.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/209206)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I can't accept this answer until tomorrow. I do not know of a way to accept a comment as an answer, therefore reiterated it here.

Comment: Don't worry, I see also the question will be closed.