# Installing Lua Modules for use in LuaLaTeX - the sequel

Tags: installing, luatex

There is a question with the same title, [Installing Lua Modules for use in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14361/), that apparently went unresolved. I'm having similar issues and at this point am out of ideas.

I'm running Debian Testing and have installed lua's xmlrpc library through the package manager. The files are installed in

```
/usr/share/lua/5.1/xmlrpc
/usr/share/lua/5.1/xmlrpc/http.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/xmlrpc/init.lua
/usr/share/lua/5.1/xmlrpc/server.lua
```

and are found alright by the system's lua installation.

I have determined that the `package.path` parameter differs between the system's lua installation and luatex. System:

```
mpalmer@holzkopf:~$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(package.path)
./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
>
```

In luatex, `/usr/share/lua` and subdirectories are missing from the path. When I set the `LUA_PATH` environmental variable to the system's path, `/usr/share/lua` and subdirectories show up in luatex's `package.path` also, but the `xmlrpc` module still isn't found. I have also tried to make `/usr/local/share/lua` (which didn't actually exist) a symlink to `/usr/share/lua`, again without success.

On the other hand, luatex does not give me an error, so presumably succeeds, with `require "socket.http"`

That module lives in `/usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua` and is found even when `/usr/share/lua` is neither symlinked nor in `package.path`. So it almost seems as if `package.path` is completely ignored by luatex.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31904/243) where LuaTeX searches for files loaded by require. `require ("socket.http")` works, because LuaTeX has this built in (mentioned [in the reference manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf) in section 3.3 "Lua Modules").

Comment: OK thanks, that was helpful. I'm still a bit foggy about why it is a good idea for luatex to depart from lua's regular module loading protocol, but at least I know now where to start.

Comment: LuaTeX uses (if initialized, but this is true if you use LuaLaTeX) kpathsea to locate the lua modules. That's just the way TeX is (web2c based distributions, to be exact).