# Moving lua code into subdirectory

Tags: luatex

I want to move all `.lua` files into the subdirectory `code` to avoid polluting the main directory with them. However, I cannot get lualatex to find them there.

Given this project layout:

```
main.tex
main.lua
code/
  test.lua
  test2.lua
```

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{package.path = './code/?.lua;' .. package.path}
\directlua{print(package.path)}
\directlua{require('test')}
\directlua{require('code/test')}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

### main.lua

```
package.path = './code/?.lua;' .. package.path
print(package.path)
require('test')
require('code/test')
```

### code/test.lua

```
require('test2')
```

### code/test2.lua

```
print('success')
```

When I run `lualatex main.tex` I get the output:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (rev 4971) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))./code/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua

! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: module 'test' not found:
        no field package.preload['test']
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'test'
        [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'test'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.5 \directlua{require('test')}

? q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

The problem seems to be that lualatex does not find the files in the subdirectory although I altered the `package.path` (which is also printed correctly!).

When I runt the same code via `lua main.lua` the output is

```
./code/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua
success
```

as expected.

For some reason `lualatex` seems not to take `package.path` into account.

Using `require('code/test.lua')` is not an option because then the dependency between `test.lua` and `test2.lua` is not picked up correctly.

What do I need to do to make lualatex find my `.lua` files in the `code` directory?

I already followed [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42878/installing-lua-modules-for-use-in-lualatex-the-sequel) to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/lua-tree-analogue-of-texmf-tree/31904#31904) but I don't see how this solves the problem (or does it state that we cannot change the package search path in lualatex?). Also, the scenario seems to be another one as I don't want to "install a systemwide" module but some scripts for this project only.

Comment: lualatex doesn't use package path by default. it uses `kpse` library which searches in `texmf` tree abd current directory. but it is possible to modify package loader to support package oath, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219228/2891

Comment: @michal.h21 So while overriding the "easy to use" default algorithm they (the lualatex authors) did not offer a replacement/command to add your own paths? I feel like it might not be an otherworldly request to be able to use subdirectories in your lua(latex) code.

Comment: you have an error in your code: `require('code/test')` should be `require('code.test')`. but it probably will not find submodules anyway

Comment: try `require('code.test')` it should work.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides michal.h21: `require(code/test)` works as well as `require(code.test)` the problem occurs with the dependency in `code/test.lua` to `code/test2.lua` which in both cases does not work because the `require` does not search in `code`.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way I have found to import relative packages in lualatex is

```
require(package.searchpath('test', './?.lua:./code/?.lua'))
```

which will find test.lua by searching ./ and ./code. It is hacky, but also clear and quick.

Adding the path loader as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219228/2891 is the more thorough solution, but that code did not immediately work for me, plus it would require figuring out the textmf lua paths.

Comment: A Warm Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The solution works, but I believe the appropriate path separator [is the semicolon](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html). That makes it work for me.

Comment: This is good for a single file, but if your lua library has multiple files (ie is a folder with several files in it), it will be problematic. I recommend placing the files where lualatex.exe is (in my case C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64) and `usepackage{luapackageloader}`

Answer (score 0):

```
local oldreq = require
require = function(p) 
    return oldreq(package.searchpath(p, './?.lua;./code/?.lua'))
end
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please explain what your shown code does? How does it solve the given issue? Please do not only throw a code, explain what is does.