# Using LuaLaTeX and SQLite3

Tags: luatex

I am trying to access SQLite databases from LuaLaTeX but am not able to load an installed `lsqlite3` package. Here's what I tried so far:

1. Took a brandnew Xubuntu 14.04 installation
2. Installed a complete TeX Live 2014
3. Installed Luarocks (which installed Lua5.1 on the way)
4. Used Luarocks to install `lsqlite3`

   uwe@luabuntu:/media/uwe$ luarocks list

   Installed rocks:

   lsqlite3
      0.9.1-2 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
5. Appended the `package.path` in the following TeX file:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}    
   \usepackage{luacode}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{luacode*}
     package.path="/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks;/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/lsqlite3; 
     /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lsqlite3.so" .. package.path

     require("lsqlite3")
   \end{luacode*}

   Hello Lua!

   \end{document}
   ```

The error I receive is the following:

> ```
> ! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:3: module 'lsqlite3' not found:
>   no field package.preload['lsqlite3']
>   [luatexbase.loader] Search failed
>   [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lsqlite3'
>   [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'lsqlite3'
>   [oberdiek.luatex.kpse_module_loader]-eroux Search failed
> stack traceback:
>   [C]: in function 'require'
>   [\directlua]:3: in main chunk.
> \luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
>
> l.9 \end{luacode*}
> ```

What must be set to have LuaLaTeX find the `lsqlite3` package?

**EDIT**

I have tried to adjust everything following the comments below:

1. Adjusted `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf`
2. Put everything into the example
3. Still get the error about the missing `lsqlite3` module with the following example

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \directlua{
   require "lualoader"
   }

   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \begin{document}

   \directlua{package.path='/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/home/uwe/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/uwe/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1//?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1//?/init.lua;./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua'
   package.cpath='/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/home/uwe/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
   require "lualoader"
   }

   \directlua{%
   local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")
   local db = sqlite3.open_memory()

   db:exec[[
     CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content);

     INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello World');
     INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Lua');
     INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Sqlite3')
   ]]

   for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
     tex.print(row.id .. " : ".. row.content )
   end

   }
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: ``lsqlite3`` is a binary module, at least in part. You probably have to set [``package.cpath``](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath) as well.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that package.path is ignored in kpathsea systems. - see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31904/243

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48193/243

Comment: @phg I have added the `cpath` setting, no success. Same error as before.

Comment: @topskip: I checked both links but have no idea how to tell `kpathsea` to use the additional path(s)

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen you call `lualoader` twice in your edit, paths must be set before it is required

Comment: Still getting the error. I think I'll give up and take the route via Python. I thought it would be easier under Linux, well...

Comment: The interpreted parts can be configured by means of the environment variable `LUAINPUTS` (example: `export LUAINPUTS="~/code/tex/pgfplots/tex//:~/code/tex/pgf/generic//:"`). There is also an environment variable `CLUAINPUTS` ... perhaps you need to adopt it? I know that DLL search paths tend to need native load procedures, in other words: environment variables (don't know how that works in LUA, though)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to modify the package loading mechanism in `Lua`. In the case of `LuaTeX`, the `kpse` library is used to load modules instead of the default mechanism that uses `package.path` and `package.cpath`. So setting these variables will not have any effect. But nothing prevents us from using both methods using a `Lua` module, `lualoader.lua`. Save the snippet below as a file in the directory containing your document:

```lua
-- lualoader.lua
-- this is copied from luatexbase.loader
local make_loader = function(path, pos, loadfunc)
  local default_loader = package.searchers[pos]
  local loader = function(name)
    local file, _ = package.searchpath(name,path)
    if not file then
      local msg = "\n\t[lualoader] Search failed"
      local ret = default_loader(name)
      if type(ret) == "string" then
        return msg ..ret
      elseif type(ret) == "nil" then
        return msg
      else
        return ret
      end
    end
    local loader,err = loadfunc(file, name)
    if not loader then
      return "\n\t[lualoader] Loading error:\n\t"..err
    end
    return loader
  end
  package.searchers[pos] = loader
end

local binary_loader = function(file, name)
  local symbol = name:gsub("%.","_")
  return package.loadlib(file, "luaopen_"..symbol)
end

make_loader(package.path,2,loadfile)
make_loader(package.cpath,3, binary_loader)
```

We use the function `make_loader` to insert a function searching `package.path` or `package.cpath` at a specified index in the `package.searchers` table. `2` for lua files, `3` for binary modules. We also need to use different functions to load a module depending on its type. We use `loadfile` for `Lua` files and slightly more complicated function for binary modules that uses `package.loadlib`.

As an example, we can try loading `lsqlite3` from `LuaTeX`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
require "lualoader"
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\directlua{%
local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")

local db = sqlite3.open_memory()

db:exec[[
  CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content);

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello World');
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Lua');
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, 'Hello Sqlite3')
]]

for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
  tex.print(row.id .. " : ".. row.content )
end

}
\end{document}
```

It is important to run LuaLaTeX with the `--shell-escape` flag, because binary libraries are blocked by default. With `--shell-escape` you can execute external programs and call binary libraries.

The example yields:

[image]

**Edit:**

As [Uwe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7615/uwe-ziegenhagen) pointed out, `luarocks` as installed by some Linux package managers may not work correctly. I experienced this on Fedora, so I installed `luarocks` from source. Another solution may be to set `package.path` and `package.cpath` to the directories listed by the command

```
luarocks path
```

On my own system, this yields:

```
$ luarocks path
export LUA_PATH='/home/michal/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/home/michal/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua'
export LUA_CPATH='/home/michal/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so;./?.so'
```

So a modified preamble would be:

```latex
\directlua{    
package.cpath = '/home/michal/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so;./?.so'
package.path = '/home/michal/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/home/michal/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua'
require "lualoader"
}
```

Comment: If I simply run the TeX code I get: "! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: module 'lualoader' not found:
 no field package.preload['lualoader']
 [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'lualoader'
 [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'lualoader'

If I save the lua-loader code in the same folder as the TeX code I get an error as well:
LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: module 'luarocks.loader' not found:
 no field package.preload['luarocks.loader']
 [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luarocks.loader'
 [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luarocks.loader'

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen `luarocks.loader` should be available if you have correctly installed `luarocks`. in this particular case it is not needed, because `lsqlite3` is installed to directory with other `Lua` libraries, but it is needed for `Lua` modules installed through `luarocks`

Comment: I installed `luarocks` via the Ubuntu package system. If I remove the line for the `luarocks.loader` I get the the following error again: `! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: module 'lsqlite3' not found: no field package.preload['lsqlite3']`

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen ah, I installed `luarocks` from the sources, I had problems when it was installed by Fedora. You may need to set `package.path` and `package.cpath` in this case

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen you're welcome :)

Comment: your `lualoader` script is the **only** working example in the world wide web :)

Comment: I had a chance to try this code out, and I discovered an edge case which was causing me problems. I tried `require("compat53.utf8")` which is a binary library and I could not load it.The problem is in the  `binary_loader` function above. The pattern for the `symbol` variable does not correctly convert `compat53/utf8` to `compat53_utf8`

Comment: @vyom does it work if you change that line to `local symbol = base:gsub("[%.%/]","_")`?

Comment: To make it work, I changed it to  `base:gsub("/","_")`, which is probably cruder. Your suggestion should work as well, but I could not think of a reason why the `.` character needs to be checked for the in the `base` string (and you don’t need `%/`, so the line could be something like `local symbol = base:gsub("[%./]","_")`.

Comment: @vyom I must say that I am actually surprised that the pattern in `local base = file:match("/([^%.]+)%.[%w]+$")` selects `compat53/utf8` from string `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/compat53/utf8.so`§

Comment: Yes, that is a another problem. I think the `binary loader` needs to be implemented differently. Maybe what we should really be doing is looking at the `name` parameter, and constructing the symbol based on that.

Comment: See [gist](https://gist.github.com/deepakjois/e1ca1ca5c4950392366271de0e2e02a7/revisions)

Comment: @vyom you are right, the updated loader seems to work correctly

Comment: Will you update the answer?

Comment: @vyom I've just updated it

Comment: I added a new answer below, to point out the existence of [luapackageloader](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luapackageloader) on CTAN which should take care of this for most people.

Comment: **Note**: you need to pass `--shell-escape` to the executable (for example `lualatex`) otherwise it would just return `nil` and cause some error such as "[\directlua]:20: attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'err')"

Comment: @user202729 thanks for the notice. you are right, in the recent versions of LuaTeX, binaries are blocked by default.

Answer (score 6):

As of May 2017, there is a package on CTAN called [luapackageloader](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luapackageloader), that allows you to modify the default package searching behavior in LuaTeX.

Once you load `luapackageloader`, doing a `require` will first try the default kpse based searcher. If the module isn’t found, it will also try to load the package from Lua’s `package.path` and `package.cpath` values.

Usage example

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
  package.path="/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks;/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/lsqlite3; 
  /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lsqlite3.so" .. package.path

  require("lsqlite3")
\end{luacode*}

Hello Lua!

\end{document}
```

**Additional note**: you can do `eval $(luarocks path)` on your shell to set the package path using environment variables which the Lua interpreter will pick up automatically. That way, you do not need to fiddle with the `package.path` yourself.

Comment: **Note**: you need to pass `--shell-escape` to the executable (for example `lualatex`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14361/installing-lua-modules-for-use-in-lualatex), I have the following line in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf`:

```
CLUAINPUTS  = .;$SELFAUTOLOC/lib/{$progname,$engine,}/lua//;/usr/lib/{$progname,$engine,}/lua//
```

But my `luarocks list` gives:

```
Installed rocks:

lsqlite3
   0.9.1-2 (installed) - /usr/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.2
```

so you may need to adjust the second path according to your installation.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

[image]

#### Searching for the package

- In normal Lua, a package is searched in `package.path` and `package.cpath`.
- In LuaTeX, a package is by-default searched with kpse.
- There are 2 ways to modify where LuaTeX searches for packages

1. modify behavior of kpse

   Modify `texmf.cnf` file, variables `LUAINPUTS` and `CLUAINPUTS`.
2. make Lua load from `package.(c)path`, then modify those

   - **With `\usepackage{luapackageloader}`, packages are searched in both kpse and `package.(c)path`.**
   - The value of `package.(c)path` can be set manually by the user within the Lua code itself, but **it's better to set environment variables** e.g. `LUA_PATH`, `LUA_CPATH`.

     If you run `eval $(luarocks path)` in bash, all processes spawned from that bash shell will inherit the environment variables.

#### Binary package

- If the package requires **binary files**, `--shell-escape` must be passed.

#### Versioning

- The package version **must be compatible with Lua version**. Do `print(_VERSION)` within Lua to check.

  To specify particular version to luarocks, do e.g. `luarocks --lua-version 5.3 path`.

Comment: This really help me a lot! Especially the graph is very helpful to understand the scheme.