# Require gives error in lualatex in texlive 2020 and Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: luatex, lua

I have tried many ways to include a module installed by luarocks in a tex file to be processed by lualatex, but all methods give me

```
/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:381: attempt to call 
a nil value (field 'cpath specification')
stack traceback:
        ...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:381: in field '?'
        ...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:403: in function <
...0/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs-basic-merged.lua:395>
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
```

I've tried [Using LuaLaTeX and SQLite3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218855/using-lualatex-and-sqlite3) and the package `luapackageloader`. I have also played with setting `package.path` and `package.cpath`. The goal for me is to load the path module from penlight. And for that, I've tried both

```lua
\directlua{
  require("pl")
  path = require("pl.path")
}
```

and

```lua
\directlua{
  path = require("path")
}
```

Everything gave the same error quoted below. What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

PS. I'm running everything on a clean Ubuntu Bionic installation.

Comment: Maybe you could change the title to "Requiring a dynamic library gives error in lualatex from TeXLive 2020" or similar, because this is what people will look for in the next weeks/months.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem or not, but I run into similar issue with `axessibility` package. Fixed by putting file `axessibility.lua` into one of the folders returned by `kpsewhich -show-path=lua`, then running `texhash` (which was a crucial step I forgot to make).

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov Marcel’s answer to my question yesterday suggests that might no longer be needed. Take a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577111/192717

Answer (score 2):

You will need to compile your document with `--shell-escape` starting with LuaTeX 1.12, which is shipped with TexLive 2020 (see
https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2020-March/007333.html).

Comment: Marcel’s answer to my question from yesterday suggests that might no longer be needed. Take a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577111/192717

Comment: @reportaman: Are you sure? Requiring a binary module should  require `--shell-escape` otherwise the argument is quite pointless.