# LuaLaTeX: Is shell-escape not required? Does it really make lualatex more vulnerable as an application?

Tags: luatex, texlive, shell-escape, security

Few weeks ago when I did a fresh install of MacTeX 2020 and tried compiling some documents with command `>>lualatex filename.tex` I would get this error: `attempt to call  a nil value (field 'cpath specification')`. Upon copy-pasting that error in browser, I got to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539621/192717) that seemed to suggest that since TeXLive 2020, lualatex needs to be run with `--shell-escape`. Though unlike the case there, I did not have any dynamic library that I was trying to load (the error occurred with pretty much any file, though all my lualatex files required an external `.lua` file which also didn't in-turn require any dynamic library). At that time I tried using `--shell-escape` and it had resolved the problem. Since then I have updated all packages once, and it seems like I no longer need `--shell-escape` for compiling same documents. Did something change? the [release notes](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/NEWS?view=markup) don't have anything new, or am I looking at the wrong release notes?

As part 2 of the question: Does `--shell-escape` make LuaLaTeX users more vulnerable to malicious code? Related to this: Now tex live utility asks a one time question to enhance security by clicking a dialog, what does it actually do?

Comment: @Davislor Yeah I didn't load minted, here are the packages I did load: geometry, fontspec, unicode-math, microtype, babel, blindtext, tikz, eso-pic, luatexbase, textpos, nodetree, and the document class was article.

Answer (score 6):

Recently there was a `lualibs` bug which caused that error to be printed whenever a module couldn't be loaded using the primary mechanism when shell-escape wasn't enabled, breaking some code relying on alternative loading locations. Yesterday this bug got fixed, which is probably why your code started working without `shell-escape`.

As long as you know which code is executed, using `shell-escape` for some purpose is fine. But since `shell-escape` allows to run arbitrary native binaries, running untrusted code with `shell-escape` enabled is basically the same as downloading untrusted applications and executing them without any restrictions. In this case, untrusted code includes code in packages, so even if you write your document yourself but use untrusted packages, these cas run arbitrary code. So especially when you don't know *why* your document should require `shell-escape`, you should probably keep it disabled.

Comment: Oh cool, in my case I was loading a .lua file using require mechanism in a directlua block. The .lua file resided in the same folder as the .tex file, and .lua file itself didn’t require/load any other file/library (it was just simple lua code). You think that applies to such a case? (as you mention about the “... whenever a module couldn’t be loaded using the primary mechanism...” Or it could be because of some different case caused by one of the packages I was loading.

Answer (score 5):

Most LuaLaTeX documents do not require `--shell-escape`.  I’ve compiled many documents with LuaLaTeX in TeX Live 2020 on Windows and Linux without the need for them.  One package that does require shell escapes is `minted`.  So do `texlua` install scripts.

It’s impossible to say what in the document required a shell escape without a MWE.

Shell escapes are a security risk in general, because they can run arbitrary code.  On Linux, I try to mitigate this by installing all TeX files as a system user with access to nothing but the TeX distribution.  All scripts therefore run as that user, not as my user account or root.

However, that’s really of little practical value.  A script that can modify the TeX installation can modify programs, which I then run with the security credentials to do basically everything but [install drivers.](https://xkcd.com/1200/)

Comment: Thanks, the reason I didn’t have a MWE is it happened with all of my files. Though as I mention all of my .tex files loaded another .lua file using a require mechanism. Seems like Marcel pointed to the source of the bug .