# What are some typical LuaTeX gotchas?

Tags: macros, errors, luatex, expansion, lua

The interaction of TeX and Lua can be quite delicate at times.  While the former has category codes and tokens, the latter has escape sequences and datatypes.  Mixing the disparate concepts of these two worlds can lead to unexpected behaviour which favours common errors, known as gotchas.

In the community wiki answer below you can find an overview of the common mistakes that people make when getting to grips with LuaTeX.

Comment: I had issues with fonts and encoding when moving from pdftex to luatex, but I'm not sure if this a) is still an issue (was some years ago) and b) is what this question is about.

Comment: @Arsenal This Q&A is more about the usage of Lua.  Also since pdfTeX switched to UTF-8 by default there shouldn't be any encoding problems anymore when migrating.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Escaping strings

When passing TeX tokens as Lua strings, characters that are special to Lua have to be escaped.  A naive example of such an error would be

```
\newcommand\justprint[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint("#1")}}
\justprint{"hello"}
```

which results in the error

```
[\directlua]:1: ')' expected near 'hello'.
\justprint #1->\directlua {tex.sprint("#1")}
```

because #1 is formally replaced by `"hello"` which gives the invalid lua syntax `tex.sprint(""hello"")`. This can be fixed easily be applying `\luaescapestring`.

```
\newcommand\justprint[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}
\justprint{"hello"}
```

> If the `luacode` package is loaded, one can replace `\directlua{tex.sprint("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}` with `\directlua{tex.sprint(\luastring{#1})}}`.

## Printing numbers

Let's try to print the number 42 and the string `foo` into the document.

```
\directlua{tex.sprint(42, "foo")}
```

But only the string `foo` shows up, what happened?

The gotcha here is that `tex.sprint` takes a variable number of arguments and performs different things depending on their types.  If there are several arguments and the first argument is a number, then it is interpreted as a category code table number and not printed into the document.  Therefore it is always a good idea to just explicitly convert anything that you want to print into a string.

```
\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(42), tostring("foo"))}
```

The second `tostring` is gratuitous in this situation, but you should always run `tostring` on function return values. Moreover, if you ever forget to convert an integer to a string, LuaTeX may silently do it for you, but beware that this undocumented feature (as of version 1.13) may be unsupported in the future.

You can also use the concatenation operator `..` as soon as one operand is a string

```
\directlua{tex.sprint((42).."foo")}
```

## Inhibiting expansion

The `\directlua` primitive fully expands its arguments which can cause errors if there is content present that is not expandable.
For example if we want to execute `\section{Title}`,

```
\directlua{tex.sprint("\section{Title}")}
```

will not work because the `\section` command is executed too early. To solve this problem the following common idiom is used:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{\section{Title}}}")}
```

The `\unexpanded` primitive will inhibit expansion and `\luaescapestring` makes sure that the leading `\s` of `\section` is not interpreted as an escape sequence.

> If the `luacode` package is loaded, one can replace `tex.sprint("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{\section{Title}}}")` with `tex.sprint(\luastringN{\section{Title}})`.

Another straightforward possibility uses the `\string` primitive together with long lua strings:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint([[\string\section{Title}]])}
```

After `\string`, `\section` is no longer considered as a command, and long lua strings do not consider `\` as a control character.

## Typesetting the result, i.e, what's returned by a Lua function

When setting up LaTeX macros that contain `\directlua` statements to do something in real time, beginners may not be aware of the fact that simply “returning” the correct object to LaTeX's control does not suffice to get it typeset; an explicit `tex.sprint` directive is required as well. Take, for example,

```
\directlua{function modify ( s )
    return ( s:gsub ( "Hello World" , "Hola Mundo" ) )
  end
}
\newcommand\modify[1]{\directlua{modify("#1")}}
```

When typing `How to say \modify{Hello World} in Spanish?` the output will be “How to say[two blank spaces]in Spanish?”

To get the desired output, it's necessary to write, say, `\newcommand\modify[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(modify("#1"))}}`.

## Comments within `\directlua`

As already seen the argument of the `\directlua` is first managed according to TeX rules. In particular, `%` starts a TeX comment:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint("this is printed% but not this comment"
   (up to the real closing quote)"
)}
```

is equivalent to

```
\directlua{tex.sprint("this is printed(up to the real closing quote)" )}
```

We observe that `\directlua` is fed with one single line of instructions. The consequence is that lua short comments apply to more instructions than expected:

```
\directlua{
  tex.sprint("One"); -- One is printed
  tex.sprint("Two"); -- but not Two
}
```

You can use long comments instead

```
\directlua{
  tex.sprint("One"); --[[ One is printed ]]
  tex.sprint("Two"); --[[ Two is printed as well ]]
}
```

or the `luacode` environment

```
\begin{luacode}
  tex.sprint("One"); -- One is printed
  tex.sprint("Two"); -- Two is print as well
\end{luacode}
```

## Sharing data

lua can have read and write access to many TeX variables. For example next LaTeX code defines a counter, prints and modifies it from the lua side, then prints its updated value from the LaTeX side:

```
\newcounter{abc}
\setcounter{abc}{421}
\directlua{
  tex.sprint(tostring(tex.getcount('c@abc')));
  tex.setcount('c@abc', 666);
}
\arabic{abc}
```

The output is "421 666". This works as well for dimensions, boxes,... Chapter 10.3 of the LuaTeX manual is of great help on the subject.

For macros this is not as transparent. We can't see the category codes from the lua side because `token.get_macro('foo')` is the detokenized content of `\foo`. Nor can we define macros with parameters with `token.set_macro`, for that we must use `tex.print`. Nevertheless, macros can be used to share information between TeX and lua (see Chapter 10.6 of the LuaTeX manual). We will illustrate this below.

On the opposite, TeX does not have any direct access to lua variables.

One of the major differences between the TeX and the lua world is that lua variables do not obey the TeX grouping mechanism. For example, next LaTeX environment prints, when closed, the number of the line containing the `\begin`:

```latex
\newenvironment{Demo}{
  \directlua{ begin_lineno = tex.inputlineno }
} {
  \directlua{ tex.sprint(begin_lineno) }
}
```

This won't work as soon as we embed a Demo environment into another one because `begin_lineno` only takes into account the last `\begin`. Using LaTeX counters instead would solve the problem.
More generally, data that obey to TeX groups should be stored on the TeX side.

## Jumping back and forth between TeX and Lua

`\directlua` allows to execute lua instructions from the TeX side whereas `tex.sprint` allows to execute TeX instructions from the lua side. We have seen how feeding `\directlua` may be tricky, now we see that printing is asynchronous, somehow

Within `\directlua` argument, the various `tex.print` functions give instructions to TeX. But these instructions are only executed at the end of `\directlua`: hereafter the content of the macro `\foo` is alternately "day" and "night",

```
\directlua{
  token.set_macro('foo', 'day');   --[[ same as \string\def\string\foo{day} ]]
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
  token.set_macro('foo', 'night'); --[[ same as \string\def\string\foo{night} ]]
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
}
```

The result is not "day night" as we may expect, it is "night night"! This is just like if all the print instructions were gathered at the very end:

```
\directlua{
  token.set_macro('foo', 'day');
  token.set_macro('foo', 'night');
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
}
```

and we see how the first line is absolutely useless. In order to obtain "day night", we would have to use two separate `\directlua`:

```
\directlua{
  token.set_macro('foo', 'day');
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
}
\directlua{
  token.set_macro('foo', 'night');
  tex.sprint([[\string\foo]]);
}
```

A corollary is that merging consecutive `\directlua` instructions is not always safe. Moreover, when the discussion between TeX and lua involves more complex instructions, some callback pattern may help:

```
\direclua{
  <lua instructions>
  tex.print(<tex instructions>)
  function callback()
    <to be performed after the tex instructions>
  end
  tex.print([[\string\directlua{callback()}]])
}
```

`tex.runtoks` or lua coroutines illustrated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/concurrently-interleaving-execution-of-lua-and-tex-in-luatex) may help in that situation, but that is advanced usage.

## A few unsorted things (need to be written out)

- finding libraries
- error reporting (line numbers might be within the `\directlua` call)
- percent and other "funny" characters and luacode package

Comment: Please modify the community wiki answer and don't post extra answers.

Comment: Related: ■ interleave TeX and Lua execution [expansion - Concurrently interleaving execution of Lua and TeX in LuaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20893) ■ more communication things: [Can the Lua part of LuaTeX know about tokens? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45293) (also have some discussion on how get_next() can weird out on unseen tokens) ■ loading pure-Lua libraries and C libraries [luatex - Using LuaLaTeX and SQLite3 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218855)