# Problem using macros in directua

Tags: luatex, directlua

I have the following external lua script:

```
-- file mylua.lua
function test(input)
   tex.sprint(input)
end
```

And the following lualatex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\directlua{dofile("mylua.lua")}

\begin{document}

This works: \directlua{test("Hello world!")}

But this doesn't: \directlua{test("\textit{Hello world!}")}
\end{document}
```

This is a simple example illustrating an error I get in a more complex code I'm writing. I moved my lua code to an external file, in order to avoid problems escaping characters. However, inevitably I have to use macros in my `\directlua` calls, and most of the times I cannot control what the macros are.

Is there any way of avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to print the Lua string `"\textit..."` but `\t` is a tab character so you need `"\\textit...."` in the Lua but `\directlua` expands its argument like `\edef` so you need to stop `\\`  expanding so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\directlua{dofile("mylua.lua")}

\begin{document}

This works: \directlua{test("Hello world!")}

But this doesn't: \directlua{test("\string\\textit{Hello world!}")}
\end{document}
```

You could also use

`\directlua{test("\luaescapestring{\detokenize{\textit{Hello world!}}}")}`

which may be better if you don't have easy control over the content.

[image]

You have loaded (but not used) the `luacode` package which offers some wrappers around `\directlua` but I find it simpler usually not to use them and control the expansion directly.

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, I don't have control as to the argument of `test()`, so I cannot manually add `\string\` every time I need it.

Comment: you can use `\detokenize{...}` around the whole thing and use `\luaescapestring{...}` to automatically double `\ ` and other needed Lua escapings, I just thought it more useful to do it by hand here to highlight what the issue is. Or you could use the luacode package functions.

Comment: @NVaughan see update

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Comment: Since the OP loads the `luacode` package, you could make use of the package's `\luastringN` macro to accomplish what `"\luaescapestring{\detokenize{...}}"` does.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The common idiom is `\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{...}}` (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550673).  Using `\detokenize` might be a bad idea because this will add spaces, e.g. `\textit{Hello}` becomes `\textit {Hello}`.  If the string is written back to TeX with the default catcode table, that is not a problem but if the string is processed in Lua this might lead to some confusion.

Comment: @HenriMenke `\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{\detokenize{\relax\relax{z}}}")}` and `\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{\relax\relax{z}}}")}` both have spaces after the `\relax` so there are some differences but it isn't clear that one is always better than the other, generally `\unexpanded` is like having `\noexpand` on every token (which adds spaces when the tokens are written out) and `\detokenize` is like having `\string` on every token (which does not add spaces)