# Generating a Star Diagram: Tikz Evaluation in LuaLatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I have run the following code in LuaLatex. I'm doing everything on overleaf, if that matters.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,graphs.standard}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [
    simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm,
    nodes={draw,circle}
    ]
    {
        subgraph C_n [n=8]; 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
            \i -- \directlua{tex.sprint(3+\i)};
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{20 pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [
    simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm,
    nodes={draw,circle}
    ]
    {
        subgraph C_n [n=8]; 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
            \i -- \directlua{tex.sprint(mod({3+\i},8))};
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The two Tikz pictures have the same code except that in the second loop, `3+\i` is replaced by `mod({3+\i},8))`. Because `3 + i % 8` is equal to 3 + i for i = 1,...,4, I should have ended up with essentially the same picture both times. However, here is what I end up with:

[image]

How can I fix this code so that the modular arithmetic is evaluated correctly?

Once I have that working, the idea is to extend the loop to {1,...,8} in order to get the full "star".

Comment: Of course, I would have to fix the off by one error before getting the loop to actually work, but the issue with modular arithmetic stands

Comment: `mod({3+\i},8)` is not valid Lua.  Try `math.mod(3+\i,8)`.  Also you fell for the typical LuaTeX gotcha: `tex.sprint(<number>)` will not do the correct thing.  Always use `tex.sprint(tostring(<number>))`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550673/what-are-some-typical-luatex-gotchas

Comment: @Henri Wow, thanks for sharing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `pgf` to compute the mod. Note that `mod` returns numbers starting from `0` so you probably want `int(1+mod(2+\i,8))` instead of `int(mod(3+\i,8))`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,graphs.standard}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [
    simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm,
    nodes={draw,circle}
    ]
    {
        subgraph C_n [n=8]; 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
            \i -- \directlua{tex.sprint(3+\i)};
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{20 pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [
    simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm,
    nodes={draw,circle}
    ]
    {
        subgraph C_n [n=8]; 
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(1+mod(2+\i,8))}]in {1,...,5}{
            \i -- \j;
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\vspace{20 pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [
    simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm,
    nodes={draw,circle}
    ]
    {
        subgraph C_n [n=8]; 
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(1+mod(2+\i,8))}]in {1,...,8}{
            \i -- \j;
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, when I tried something like this earlier the expressions weren't evaluated properly; I had decided that the issue was using pgf in the context was the issue, hence the weird approach. In any case, this works! Thanks for the help.