TeXlive and luacom
I am trying to extract data from an excel sheet with a lua script and therefore need luacom. TeXlive (2024, Windows) doesn't recognize this library when requiring, because it doesn't come with it.
Linking the dll directly is also not working for me (I think because it is for a different lua version and I am not able to build a working one).
I tried to install luacom through luarocks, which is also not working for me, because I get build errors.
Downloading the dll directly from their website is also not working.
The closest I’ve come to a working solution is by downloading the DLL from IUP and referencing it with the following code:
assert(package.loadlib("d:\\Downloads\\iup-3.31-Lua53_Win64_bin\\luacom.dll", "luacom_openlib")) ()

However, when I run this code, the compilation process halts without producing any errors.
This is what I managed to do so far:
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{scrap = require('scrap')}

\newcommand{\testing}[4]{
\directlua{scrap.openExcel(#1, #2, #3, #4)}
}

\begin{document}

\testing{D:/OneDrive/Dokumente/UNI/WG Wien/Ausgaben WG.xlsx}{Oktober}{19}{18}

\end{document}



package.loadlib("d:\\Downloads\\iup-3.31-Lua53_Win64_bin\\luacom.dll", "luacom_openlib")

local function openExcel(path, sheetName, row, column)
    local excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = true
    local workbook = excel.Workbooks:Open(path)
    local worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    local cellValue = worksheet.Cells(row, column).Value2
    tex.sprint("Value in cell (" .. row .. ", " .. column .. "): " .. tostring(cellValue))
    workbook:Close(false)
    excel:Quit()
    excel = nil
end

return { openExcel = openExcel }



This is the error I get.

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 system commands enabled.
(d:/VS-CodeProjects/LuaTesting/src/testingOut.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-07-20>
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
No file testingOut.aux.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[\directlua]:1: <name> expected near '/'.
\testing ...tlua {scrap.openExcel(#1, #2, #3, #4)}
                                                   
l.11 ...I/WG Wien/Ausgaben WG.xlsx}{Oktober}{19}{18}
                                                  
(./testingOut.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 413 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:7,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on testingOut.log.


I also tried loading luacom with
package.cpath = "d:\\Downloads\\iup-3.31-Lua53_Win64_bin\\?.dll;" .. package.cpath
require('luacom')

which results in

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 system commands enabled.
(d:/VS-CodeProjects/LuaTesting/src/testingOut.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-07-20>
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))./scrap.lua:2: module 'luacom' not found:
    no field package.preload['luacom']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'luacom'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'luacom'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./scrap.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.3 \directlua{scrap = require('scrap')}
                                      
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
No file testingOut.aux.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[\directlua]:1: <name> expected near '/'.
\testing ...tlua {scrap.openExcel(#1, #2, #3, #4)}
                                                   
l.11 ...I/WG Wien/Ausgaben WG.xlsx}{Oktober}{19}{18}
                                                  
(./testingOut.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 413 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:7,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on testingOut.log.


Now everything should be set up correctly, but I always get this error when trying to build luacom.
luarocks install luacom --lua-version=5.3
Installing https://luarocks.org/luacom-1.4-1.src.rock

luacom 1.4-1 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.3-1 provided by VM: success)
Warning: variable CFLAGS was not passed in build_variables
Makefile:73: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Error: Build error: Failed building.

I followed this guide and many others but I always get the same error. Even using this script I get the same error.
Running it with MSVC nmake I get this error:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility, Version 14.40.33813.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

        if not exist .\lib  mkdir .\lib
        if not exist .\obj\lua5.3  mkdir .\obj\lua5.3
        cl /c /DLUACOM_DLL=\"luacom.dll\" /EHsc -I..\lua5.3\include -I.\include -I.\src\library -DWIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -nologo -MD -Zi -O2 -DNDEBUG -DCOMPAT51 /Fo.\obj\lua5.3/LuaAux.obj .\src\library\LuaAux.cpp
LuaAux.cpp
c:\Users\demet\luacom-1.4-1\luacom-1.4\src\library\LuaAux.h(14): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "lua.h": No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "cl /c /DLUACOM_DLL=\"luacom.dll\" /EHsc -I..\lua5.3\include -I.\include -I.\src\library -DWIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -nologo -MD -Zi -O2 -DNDEBUG -DCOMPAT51 /Fo.\obj\lua5.3/LuaAux.obj .\src\library\LuaAux.cpp": Rückgabe-Code "0x2"
Stop.


What should I do to correctly build it, or can I download the correct dll somewhere?
When using the luacom.dll from IUP, I get the following error running my .tex:
multiple Lua VMs detected

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks again for all the help I got :). For anyone interested, this is what I managed to do: https://github.com/Mekronix/excel_utils.git

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short TeX code you have so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

see this for a fairly extensive answer on setting up luarocks with lualatex https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218855/using-lualatex-and-sqlite3/639329#639329

In addition to the linked question – which explains where you have to put the library on your system – you should pass the path and month arguments as strings to Lua (\newcommand{\testing}[4]{\directlua{scrap.openExcel("#1", "#2", #3, #4)}}or \newcommand{\testing}[4]{\directlua{scrap.openExcel([[#1]], [[#2]], #3, #4)}}).

as a general rule: don't compile on onedrive.

the message tells you there is a syntax error on line 73 of the Makefile. probably off-topic: and I strongly recommend against using weird characters in file and directory names e.g. spaces.

Is it possible to download the DLL from somewhere, or could someone provide it?

Do you need this repeatedly while still editing the spreadsheet? If not I would take the much simpler route of saving the spreadsheet as csv text files which you can directly read in luatex without any special libraries

Exactly that is what I need.

I can't comment on actually using luacom since I don't have Excel (or Windows) installed, but I was able to build it on Linux.
If you like downloading random binaries from strangers on the internet, then you can download my copy of luacom.dll; otherwise, you can follow the instructions below:

(prerequisite) Install mingw64-gcc-c++ and Wine.

Download the Windows LuaTeX binaries and the Lua 5.3 source, and save it somewhere convenient.

Download the luacom source, make a folder called build/ inside of it, and place the following Makefile inside of it:
# Configuration variables
lua_path := /home/max/Projects/texlive-source/libs/lua53/lua53-src/src/
luatex_path := .

# Base constants
cc := x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
cpp := x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
cpp_flags := \
    -DLUA_COMPAT_5_1 \
    -DLUACOM_DLL='"luacom.dll"' \
    -flto=auto \
    -Os \
    -pipe \
    -s
ld_flags := \
    -static-libgcc \
    -static-libstdc++ \
    -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,--whole-archive \
    -lwinpthread \
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-Bdynamic
includes := \
    -I. \
    -I../include/ \
    -I../src/library/ \
    -I${lua_path}

# Build LuaCOM objects
luacom_object_names := \
    LuaAux luabeans luacom LuaCompat tCOMUtil tLuaCOMClassFactory \
    tLuaCOMConnPoints tLuaCOM tLuaCOMEnumerator tLuaCOMException \
    tLuaCOMTypeHandler tLuaControl tLuaDispatch tLuaObject tLuaObjList tLuaTLB \
    tLuaVector tStringBuffer tUtil

luacom_object_paths := $(patsubst %, %.o, ${luacom_object_names})

%.lo: ../src/library/%.lua
    texluac -o $@ $<

%.loh: %.lo
    texlua ../mak/bin2c.lua $< > $@

%.o: ../src/library/%.cpp luacom5.loh
    ${cpp} -c $< -o $@ ${cpp_flags} ${includes}

# Build LuaCOM DLL
libraries := \
    -L. \
    -L${luatex_path} \
    -lgdi32 \
    -lhtmlhelp \
    -llua53w64 \
    -lluacom \
    -lole32 \
    -loleaut32 \
    -lshlwapi \
    -luuid

.DEFAULT_GOAL := luacom.dll
luacom.dll: ../src/dll/luacom_dll.cpp ../src/dll/luacom_dll.def $    {luacom_object_paths}
    ${cpp} -shared -o $@ $^ ${cpp_flags} ${includes} ${ld_flags} ${libraries}


Run make.

Save the following file as test.tex:
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2
\directlua{
    package.loadlib("./luacom.dll", "luaopen_luacom")()
    for k, v in pairs(luacom) do
        print(k, v)
    end
}
\end


Run the file as follows:
luatex.exe --shell-escape --ini ./test.tex

My output:
002c:fixme:winediag:loader_init wine-staging 9.17 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
002c:fixme:winediag:loader_init Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: […].
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (INITEX)
system commands enabled.
(./test.texImportIUnknown       function: 00006FFFFBD02820
CreateInprocObject      function: 0000000001928EB0
GetEnumerator   function: 00006FFFFBD08F22
StartLog        function: 00006FFFFBD05565
CLSIDfromProgID function: 00006FFFFBD05C37
ShowHelp        function: 00006FFFFBD05387
ExposeObject    function: 00006FFFFBD07DD2
RevokeObject    function: 00006FFFFBD06002
ProgIDfromCLSID function: 00006FFFFBD05E0A
ImplInterface   function: 00006FFFFBD0A84F
GetTypeInfo     function: 00006FFFFBD05533
StartMessageLoop        function: 00006FFFFBD046A6
RegisterObject  function: 00006FFFFBD060B9
Connect function: 00006FFFFBD0ABBA
CreateLocalObject       function: 0000000001928E80
NewControl      function: 00006FFFFBD0B817
DumpTypeInfo    function: 00006FFFFBD07CA8
DetectAutomation        function: 00006FFFFBD047F2
UnRegisterObject        function: 00006FFFFBD06B57
ImplInterfaceFromTypelib        function: 00006FFFFBD0A411
ExportConstants function: 0000000001928E50
ViewTypeLib     function: 0000000001929000
CreateObject    function: 00006FFFFBD0AE77
GetObject       function: 00006FFFFBD0B137
NewLibrary      function: 000000000192A800
RoundTrip       function: 00006FFFFBD09FA7
DumpTypeLib     function: 0000000001928FD0
EndLog  function: 00006FFFFBD055EC
isMember        function: 00006FFFFBD0543B
FillTypeLib     function: 0000000001928FA0
FillTypeInfo    function: 0000000001928F70
_copyFields     function: 0000000001928F40
GetIUnknown     function: 00006FFFFBD054D7
GetType function: 0000000001928F10
NewObject       function: 00006FFFFBD0B810
pairs   function: 0000000001928EE0
GetCurrentDirectory     function: 00006FFFFBD01883
config  table: 0000000001918B90
CreateLuaCOM    function: 00006FFFFBD0B821
LoadTypeLibrary function: 00006FFFFBD07862
releaseConnection       function: 00006FFFFBD0996D
addConnection   function: 00006FFFFBD097F0
)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.




not sure how well this would work on windows. presumably the OP could skip wine, but they'd need a gnu toolchain?

@cfr You should be able to compile from Windows if you run everything from a  MSYS2 shell, although I haven't tested this. But once you've built luacom, you get a regular .dll that runs on Windows without any dependencies, so you can always skip the building step and download the copy that I linked in the answer.

Thanks a lot :). Do I have to tell lua where it can find excel, as I get attempt to index a nil value (local 'excel')?

@Mekronix It's been a really long time since I've done anything with COM, but I think that everything is stored in the registry, so I don't think that you need to do anything specific to make it find Excel. If you add print(luacom.config.last_error) right below the local excel =  […] line, it should hopefully give you a hint as to what's going on.

I get 'COM error:(../src/library/luacom.cpp,507):' which doesn't really tell me anything.

thanks. strictly speaking, your comment is false. but I'm sure it is true if I replace 'you' with 'somebody :-).

@Mekronix That means that the line CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, context, IID_IDispatch, (void**)&pdisp) failed. Looking at the possible reasons for failure, I'm not seeing anything obvious. Maybe test the Excel COM from PowerShell (example) to make sure that it's working?

Thank you so much it finally works :) (this solved my problem)
